# current = current * 10 + (c - '0');

Tags: c, input

I'm trying to read unknown number of integers by this piece of code:

```
while (1) {
        int c = getchar ();
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        else if (isdigit (c))
            current = current * 10 + (c - '0');
        else {
            total += current;
            current = 0;
        }
}
```

I know what `current = current * 10 + (c - '0')`; does but I don't know why is there `c - '0'`. Could you explain it to me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Side note: current is not initialized in you code.

Comment: @hivert it may be initialised above the `while` loop.

Answer (score 8):

`c - '0'` is a rudimentary way of turning a single ASCII digit into an integer.

For example, if `c` is equal to `'9'`, then its integer value is `0x39`. The ASCII value for `'0'` is `0x30`, so, `0x39-0x30 == 0x09` which is equal to the integer value `9`.

Here is the ASCII table for digits:

```
chr  hex   dec
'0'  0x30  48
'1'  0x31  49
'2'  0x32  50
'3'  0x33  51
'4'  0x34  52
'5'  0x35  53
'6'  0x36  54
'7'  0x37  55
'8'  0x38  56
'9'  0x39  57
```

Comment: By the way, fact that the digit characters go `'0', '1', ... '9'` is not specific of ASCII: It is valid in EBCDIC as well, and in fact, mandated by the C standard.

Answer (score 5):

The character `'0'` does not have ASCII value 0. However, fortunately the character `'1'` does have ASCII value `'0' + 1`, and so forth through 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9. Therefore (pseudo code) `'n' - '0' == n` holds for each digit.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but `'n'-'0'` is constant and equal to `62` (at least in ASCII).

Answer (score 1):

The digits are represented in ASCII by increasing values: `0` is 48, `1` is 49, and so on. Since characters in `C` are just integers in disguise, you can subtract the ASCII value of `0` from any other digit to obtain the numerical value of the digit.  For example, `'1' - '0'` is the same as `49 - 48` which is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

C specifies the 10 decimal digits, not surprisingly, as

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

C11 §5.2.1 further states "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

Thus when assessing a string for *characters* that are digits, the language *guarantees* that subtracting `'0'` from a decimal digit `char` will result in its integer value.

```
if (isdigit (c))
  int value = c - '0';
```

This is *not* dependent on `char` using ASCII.